# Angular 6 not recognizing .sass syntax even though configured for Sass

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli

I created a new project using the Angular cli using the following command:

```
ng new myProject --style=sass
```

All of my components generate sass files and my main stylesheet is also sass. However, whenever I try to compile and run the code (I am using "ng s") I get the following error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/elements/tabs/tabs.component.sass
Module build failed:
    height: 40px
                  ^
      Invalid CSS after "...height: 40px; }": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "{"
```

The lines referenced in the sass file looks like this (referencing line 4):

```
@import "./../../../variables.sass"

//Regular Tabs
.tabs-container
      height: 40px
      background: $app-black
      .tab
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive
        font-size: 1.1em
        width: 120px
        padding-top: 10px
        padding-left: 20px
        padding-right: 20px
        color: $app-white

        display: flex
        justify-content: center
```

No idea why it is breaking on this file in particular, as all of my other files use sass as well.

I am using Angular ^6.0.3 and in my angular.json file I see:

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myProject": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "sass",
        },
   …
```

Why is Angular not recognizing the sass indent syntax?

Comment: What are the surrounding lines? +/- 10 so we have a better picture.

Comment: as @Phix said, provide the full file, it seems like css invalid format and nothing to do with angular.

Comment: I just added the rest of the file for ya. And yeah, it actually is invalid CSS format. It is supposed to be recognizing the sass format as far as I understand, which uses indention and new lines instead of curly braces and semi-colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out. Saw the issue when I was putting my code into the question. The error confused me a bit as it gives information on the css file created by the sass pre-compiler and not the actual sass file.

I had an indention issue caused by some editor configurations in my ide. Whenever I saved it was adding some extra indentions. The first place it occurred was after the 4th line.

```
@import "./../../../variables.sass"

//Regular Tabs
.tabs-container
      height: 40px
      background: $app-black
      .tab
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive
        font-size: 1.1em
```

Should actually be:

```
@import "./../../../variables.sass"

//Regular Tabs
.tabs-container
  height: 40px
  background: $app-black
  .tab
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive
    font-size: 1.1em
```

I changed the configuration in the ide and was able to save the file with the correct indentions and it compiled perfectly.